# Cannot create an NVMe shared namespace and attach it to both primary and secondary controllers

Tags: ssd, namespace, nvme

I tried creating a namespace on a Samsung PM1735 NVMe SSD then attach it to primary (0x41) and secondary (0x1) controllers, but it's attaching only to the primary controller (I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04):

```
sudo nvme create-ns /dev/nvme0 -s 26214400 -c 26214400 -b 4096
sudo nvme attach-ns /dev/nvme0 --namespace-id=1 --controllers=0x41,0x1
NVMe status: NS_IS_PRIVATE: The namespace is private and is already attached to one controller(0x2119)
```

It looks like the namespace is private and I need to create a shared namespace. Then I found this sharing option in nvme ns-create command [help](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/nvme-cli/nvme-create-ns.1.en.html):

```
-m, --nmic
Namespace multipath and sharing capabilities.
```

The problem is it's not working:

```
sudo nvme create-ns /dev/nvme0 -s 26214400 -c 26214400 -b 4096 -m
create-ns: option requires an argument -- 'm'
```

Does anybody know what argument should I pass to this option in order to create a shared namespace so that I can attach it to both controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched libnvme source [code](https://github.com/linux-nvme/libnvme/blob/v1.5/src/nvme/types.h#L1949) and found out there is a single valid value for `--nmic` argument and that's `1` for shared namespace.

I created the namespace with `-m 1` and I was able to attach it to both primary and secondary controllers.